How can I prevent WSL from running when PyCharm is launched?
When PyCharm is opened, WSL starts running and the "vmmemWSL" process consumes a large amount of memory. But I'd like to use PyCharm without WSL running concurrently. Is there a way to prevent WSL from starting when PyChanging the startup settings or configuration to avoid running "wsl --shutdown" every time after opening PyCharm? And I don't want limit the memory of WSL.
running "wsl --shutdown" every time after opening PyCharm, but it's too troublesome

Possibly it's this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-172097 . A related/similar kind of ticket (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-171655) says fixed for 2024.3.1...  You can try the following: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-171655#focus=Comments-27-11078225.0-0

You are very welcome. The link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-171655 has been helpful to me. Just turn off the wsl.use.remote.agent.for.nio.filesystem regedit in pycharm

You'll need to change your PyCharm project interpreter settings to use a local Python environment instead of WSL.
Follow these steps:

Open PyCharm Settings/Preferences
Go to Project → Python Interpreter
Click the gear icon → Add
Choose "System Interpreter" or "Virtualenv Environment" instead of "WSL"
Select your local Python installation or create a new virtualenv

This will prevent PyCharm from automatically starting WSL when opening projects.

ssory, I have been using conda all along and have not used the WSL Interpreter.

remove the wsl and docker plugins

oh, i will use the wsl and docker sometimes
